# Is there a way to make a GUI in C# without WPF or Visual Studio (using code only)?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I'm new To C# and .NET. I used to make games in `Unity`. I have a powerful knowledge in `Python`.

2 Years ago I learned to use `Tkinter` for making GUI it was good to use for me because I can build from the code whatever I want. I didn't use `qt` or any other similar apps.

When I moved To C# I didn't use [Microsoft Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/) to learn the basics or use WPF, because I don't have space on my drive, also I don't like to drag and drop buttons, and other controls. I'm using [Microsoft Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and the command prompt, to run my program.

Is there any library that I can use to write a GUI with no need to use design apps?

I searched the internet, but didn't find much. Many people prefer to use WPF because its easy. Maybe I don't like the easy way, so any help?

**Edit:**

I said before I'm not using Visual Studio. So what to do for a person that have a simple text editor and run his program throw the command prompt, and that guy want to use a simple library to make a `Graphical User Interface` just like using `Tkinter` in python.

Comment: what you are looking for is (even tho i dont recommend it now that WPF is available) "windows forms"

Comment: @DenisSchaf I don't want to use WPF I want to code everything by myself .

Comment: I mean you can use WinForms, which is outdated and WPF is here to replace it. You can also use any GUI library you can find which fits your interests, however WPF is really powerful and I wouldn't recommend any other library at the moment.

Comment: "is There any library" and "I want to code everything by myself" is a bit of a contradiction. After all, WPF is also only a library.

Comment: I'll not recommend it, but since you don't mind the hard way, you can call the Windows APIs directly. Google "CreateWindowEx c#".

Comment: @KlausGütter I mean using a library of course I cant make my own method to make  a GUI And for the "I want to code everything by myself" I mean No Drag And Drop Like WPF

Comment: You can write WPF directly as XAML without any drag and drop. You can even create the WPF elements in C# if you really like to do so.

Comment: @HansKilian It is Not about the Hard way. I have a little space on my pc And  I prefer to use library to code instead of drag and drop But thanks for "Google "CreateWindowEx c#"" I will read more about it.

Comment: It's not necessary to drag-and-drop in WPF. You can do everything without opening a single XAML file, or opening the toolbox, just in pure C# code. The same applies for WinForms, Visual Studio only gives you an easy start by opening design tools first. Check it out, and read a bit about how it all works before further assuming that WPF must be drag-and-dropped.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I do not have Visual Studio So I can't use WPF I said that So when people answer me know that I don't have the visual studio so they wont suggest to me using WPF because I do like writing the code like Tkinter in python. And I didn't say I "assuming that WPF must be drag-and-dropped." But instead I said "I searched the Internet But didn't find much. many people prefer to use WPF because its easy". That's when I searched for a tutorials or anything similar.

Comment: hmmm... Okay, you use VS Code as IDE (since VS is too heavy load for your HDD). This doesn't necessarily mean, you can't build a WPF app. Googe: "vs code wpf", one of the results is: [Building WPF Applications in Visual Studio Code with PowerShell](https://blog.ironmansoftware.com/wpf-vs-code-powershell/). For C# (or .net desktop apps, to say) WPF is the current UI-Framework, AFAIK, so I think you will need to get familiar with it.

Comment: WPF stands for Windows Presentation Foundation, and it is a framework (just like .NET) which creates and manages UI elements based on your definitions and code (either in XAML or C#). Therefore if you want, you can use WPF even by coding in Notepad; it is not coupled with Visual Studio. If you do not want to use it, you can go for Winforms, but it is the old framework and not supported, so it is not recommended. You can also use any other third party UI frameworks (Gtk, etc), but if your plan is developing Windows apps, WPF is the better way for now.

Comment: @JackQx: You can develop a WPF app in Notepad and build it on the command-line using the .NET Core CLI if you want to. Using an IDE is not required.

Comment: This Video may help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8snKUcvaMmc                     
                                                                                                                                    You can technically add any control you want from C# instead of using XAML: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: With the newly introduced WPF Hot Reload, it just make no more sense to do design without Visual Studio. Your "easy way" becomes the hard way.